# Facebook API: do a FQL query using Open Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How can I do a FQL query like the following by using the Open Graph API?

“SELECT name FROM page WHERE CONTAINS(“music/band”)”

More specifically, I seek a way to get all the facebook pages of a specific category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get Pages by category, you can only use the Search API to search Pages by name: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1#search